# Wordpress site extremely slow after migrating to Azure App Service and Azure Database for MySQL Flexible Sever

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice, azure-database-mysql

I was previously running both my wordpress application and the mysql database server installation inside the same Linux Virtual Machine on Azure. I recently migrated both to Azure App Service and Azure Database for MySQL Flexible Server respectively in the same region - East US. Unfortunately, this has really slowed down the application and page load times have increased to an average of 11 s from 1 s. I served all static files from a CDN but to no avail. Checking the network waterfall, the scripts blocking the page are calls to admin-ajax.php. Increasing the compute of both services to a ridiculous size (there is no traffic right now) only improves the speed to 6 s. Since, both services are in the same region I do not believe there can be such a significant network latency between the server and db. What additional steps can I take to troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: Please refer [Troubleshoot slow app performance issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-performance-degradation)

Answer (score 0):

If you isolate the slowness endpoints and if its due to SQL then I suggest to configure VNET integration with app service and use service endpoint, Microsoft.SQL at subnet of app service integrated subnet such that some of limitation regarding number of sockets and network latency rule out and should observe performance gain. Parallelly you need to check SQL execution time either using profiling of queries or using Performance recommendations.